# Rename a range of Excel Column Titles through iterate certain strings

Tags: python, excel, pandas, loops

I am trying to rename a range of Excel Column Titles through iterating 3 different values(string) in Python. I want them to have these 3 values to be in certain sequence.

For example, I have columns range from 1 to 100, and I want to column 1 title= Terminal ID.  column 2 title= ECR ID. column 3 title=IP Address. column 4 title= Terminal ID column 5 title= ECR ID column 6 title=IP Address etc.

Preferably if it can be done using Pandas but any other Python models is fine too. Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
with open ("your_file.csv", "r") as file:
    lines = []
    for line in file:
        lines.append(line.strip().split(";")

import csv
with open ("your_file.csv", "w", newline = '') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter = ";")
    writer.writerow(["Terminal ID", "ECR ID", "IP Adress", "Terminal ID", ...])
    for line in range(1, len(lines)):
        writer.writerow(line)
```

Should read all of the content of file then change the whole file to title and than add all the other rows.

Comment: Please describe, what did you change and why, to help others identify the problem and understand this answer

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your code with different file extensions csv or xlsx. but I keeps getting this error message"TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable". Would you be able to expand your answer please? Sorry I am new with programming and Python. Do I not need to add the for or while loop in here?